How to automate tradingview.com with binance to automaticly buy and sell based on indicator
I want to automate buying and selling on tradingview.com based on loaded indicator.
I have connected tradingview.com with binance.
I want to trade BTCUSDT.
I have loaded UT Bot Alerts indicator into tradingview.com.
That indicator gives me "BUY" and "SELL" signals.
Is there a way to automate buying and selling, so that I do not need to do that manualy?
For example, to say:
when ever I get "BUY" indicator, BUY me BTC for 20USDT, and when I get "SELL" indicator, sell BTC for amount of 20USDT.
And, of course, do this for specific timeframe, for example if chart is set to 5 minutes, or 30 minutes.
Please see picture below, so when I get buy, the bot should buy, and when i get sell, the bot should sell.


How to Set up Signal Trading With TradingView
Go to the USDⓈ-M trading interface. Go to the [Strategy] tab and choose [Webhook Signal Trading].
Click [Create New Webhook].


copy and paste the string for "Message"

copy and paste webhook url


Is this going to trade only when signal from indicator appears?

the example is for UT Long. you must repeat these steps for UT Short
